# Concatenate distinct non blank values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, concatenation

I would like to concatenate the data from source column when Id is the same, while excluding blanks. (Expected result shown below). I want to create a measure and I've used the following measure, which is giving me additional delimiters where there are nulls (For eg: a,,b or ,a,b).
Could you let me know the best way to do this?

```
Concat =
CONCATENATEX (
    VALUES ( 'Table'[Source] ),
    'Table'[Source],
    ", "
)
```

Input

| Id | Source |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Excel |
| 1 | SAP |
| 1 | Axalant |
| 2 | SAP |
| 2 |  |
| 2 | SAP |

Expected Result

| Id | Source |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Excel, SAP, Axalant |
| 2 | SAP |

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to first filter out blanks from the table. Since VALUES() only accepts columns as input, you also have to switch to DISTINCT(), which accepts table inputs too. (The result of FILTER() is a table.)

```
ConcatNoBlanks = 
CONCATENATEX(
    DISTINCT(
        FILTER(
            'Table',
            'Table'[Source] <> BLANK()
        )
    ),
    'Table'[Source],
    ", "
)
```

[image]

Note that the extra "," in the 2nd row is gone now.